# Is there a decent book or section in opposition to many of Nietzsce's concepts in "Beyond Good and Evil"?

Tags: reference-request, nietzsche

**It would also be neat to discover a list or work that has brief critiques of major philosophical ideas or texts.**

---

Related, I found this site:

https://www.denizcemonduygu.com/philo/browse

→ Disagreement/contrast/refutation connections to these ideas:

- There is no God and we do not have immortal souls - namely *The Gay Science*
- The world is all there is--we should embrace it - namely [?]
- A life lived to the full doesn't need to derive its meaning from our abilities from outside itself - namely [?]

(minor tangential questions)

Comment: Probably Gyorgy Lukacs’ “The Destruction of Reason”.  You see this book sort of repeated in  Habermas, “The Philosophical Discourse of Modernity” (1985). The emphasis is on Reason, the Enlightenment, and not on Nietzsche’s all facts are interpretations. But they are not taking Nietzsche down book by book etc.

Comment: The “Modern” is seen as a natural progression of Reason. So Habermas also addressed the Postmodern later on. He was involved in this discussion. (Nietzsche as the grandfather of Postmodernism).

Comment: In Art, the “Modern” is used somewhat differently than it is in philosophy. It is sort of a confused mess, but the emphasis in art was moving away from representation, tonality (music) to the material itself in visual art (just the colors, arrangements on canvas, the materials etc) and just more as music for the sake of music. Not necessarily music that pleases the ear, in Schoenberg etc.

Comment: If one admits that " being opposed to " is a symmetric relation ( a reciprocal one), then the answer is " all books written before Nietzsche" , since, broadly speaking, Nietzsche is himself opposed to the whole philosophical tradition. For example, Descartes' "cogito" is opposed to Nietzsche's critique of Descartes' " cogito" in BGE.